# For Loop does not reach 5

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I am working on CodeAcademy trying to learn some JavaScript and I have encountered this interesting thing actually. Please take a look here:

```
for(var counter = 100; counter > 0; counter = counter - 5){
    console.log(counter);
}
```

Here I tell the loop to loop through an print the counter number as long as counter is bigger than 0, however it only ends up printing 100..95..90 etc down to 5. 
I do know how to fix this, by just adding a simple equals sign just after the bigger than sign.
Like this:

```
for(var counter = 100; counter >= 0; counter = counter - 5){
    console.log(counter);
}
```

But I am interested in knowing why this doesn't work differently?? I mean it ends the output with a 5, 5 is bigger than 0, isn't it?? When I do put a equals sign before the bigger than sign, it really should output some undefined number cause it should loop even then counter is equal to 0. My head hurts from this.
Could someone please explain, thank you :)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for, specifically "An expression to be evaluated before each loop iteration."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it should not continue the loop once it reaches zero. The way for loops work is this:

```
for (initialization; condition; increment) {
    body;
}
```

And it performs these operations in this order:

```
initialization
loop {
    condition true? then:
        body
        increment
    else:
        stop loop
}
```

So when the counter reaches zero, the condition will be false, and the body will not be executed with the counter having value "0", it will simply stop. When you put >=, however, the condition is still true at that point.

Answer (score 2):

The English translation of the "for" loop is:

1. Set counter to 100
2. If counter > 0 is not true, end this block
3. Run this code block (in this case, log counter)
4. Reduce counter by 5
5. Go back to step 2

So in this case, if counter is zero, it is not > 0 and therefore the code doesn't go back to step 2. Whereas in the second case, it is >= 0 so it runs through one last time.

Answer (score 1):

Let's see what's happening here,

When you say `counter > 0`, then it should continue till it is *strictly* greater than zero. Since zero is not greater than itself, therefore the loop stops at 5.

When you change the expression to `counter>=0`, then, it tells the compiler to continue till counter is greater than OR equal to zero, therefore it goes on to print zero as well.

Comment: So it is actually fairly correct to use the (bigger than or equal to) sign within this loop? Would you recommend that, or something else? :)

Comment: What do you say? bout that?

Comment: It is correct to use `>=` sign in this case. There are multiple ways to make it reach zero. The most straightforward is to keep `counter>=0`, otherwise you can say `counter>-1`